# CASE function setting wrong values

Tags: formula

We have a CASE() function on a Field Update for which the Workflow criteria is **Custom_Field1__c NOT EQUAL TO null** then Update another Custom_Field2__c using below formula:

```
CASE(Custom_Field3__c,
     "4004","6835",
     "4001","6830",
     "4002","6831",
     "")
```

This is not working as expected!

Instead of Setting Custom_Field2__c = 6835 when Custom_Field3__c == 4004, System is setting the value for Custom_Field2__c = blank and Setting the same field = 6835 when Custom_Field3__c == 4001. And when i change Custom_Field3__c = 4002, i am seeing Custom_Field2__c = 6830.

I couldn't find anything in debug logs too! Did anyone experience this kind of behavior before?

[image]

Comment: My concern is that it seems you have filtered out logic in an attempt to hide some potentially proprietary information and the formula you have here is not a true representation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just set up a test in my org using your exact formula/criteria and it works fine, if you can provide a more accurate representation of your formula I will take another look, as it stands, other than the missing comma, there are no issues with what you are describing.

Comment: @gNerb I've tried the same thing in a dev org and it was working fine but i am not able to understand what's going on wrong here.

Comment: @gNerb If you look at the screenshot i added to the post. Magic code is getting updated by a field update which is evaluated whenever Type value is changed.

And based on Magic Code, below two fields Agency Object and Index Code are updated.

This is the actual formula:

`CASE(Magic_Code__c, 
"4044","6835", 
"4001","N/A", 
"4004","1001", 
"4006","1002", 
"4008","1003", 
"4010","1004",  
"4050","6380", 
"4052","6831",  
"")`

In the same screenshot, value you see for Agency object is different than what it is in the CASE function. Prior value of Magic Code was 4052.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that you are missing a comma (,) after your second last line before "")

It should be:

```
CASE(Custom_Field3__c,
 "4004","6835",
 "4001","6830",
 "4002","6831",
 "")
```

Comment: Would that not cause a syntax error? Even if SFDC is smart enough to add the strings together the number of params should be incorrect.

Comment: Case works as follows: Case(Field_To_Parse, value1, result1, value2, result2, else)

Comment: Right, so `CASE(Custom_Field3__c, "4004","6835", "4001","6830", "4002","6831""")` would translate to `Cast(field_to_parse, value1, result1, value2, result2,value3,result3)` with no default. That means that if you do not get an error for missing the comma you will get an error for incorrect number of parameters.

Comment: I just confirmed that I am correct, the error for missing the comma is `Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'` which means you answer doesn't actually address the issue. The missing comma is most likely a translation error, read my comment on OP's post.

Comment: I'd probably go for this and include a blank default at the end if the value isnt in there:   CASE(field_to_parse, value1, result1, value2, result2, value3, result3, "")

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, you are correct, there is a syntax error, but the syntax error is not causing the behavior OP is describing. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JoeHayes Comma you are referring to is in the actual formula but i missed it here in the question, sorry.